# How to open browser with extension already enabled

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver

I get the following code to open chromedriver with extension but this extension is disabled, Is there any way that when chrome is launched, it launch with enabled extension -

```
 chrome_options = Options()
 chrome_options.add_extension('C:\Python\extension_3_19_6_0.crx')

 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
 driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the line you are looking for is something like this:

```
String pathToExtension = 
“C:\\Users\\home\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User 
Data\\Default\\Extensions\\mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi\\2.3.1_0”;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(“–load-extension=” + pathToExtension);
```

Here is an excellent guide on this topic: https://seleniumjava.com/2016/05/22/start-the-chrome-browser-with-extensions/

Comment: It's actually `--load-extension=` i.e. with two dashes rather than one. Also, to load more than one extension at the same time, don't repeat the option, but rather separate several paths with a comma, like `--load-extension=foo,bar,baz`